# How to define a weak-perspective camera in openGL?

Tags: opengl, camera

I know how to define the perspective camera as well as weak-perspective camera in the Math.
But how to define a weak-perspective camera () in openGL?

Comment: Can you walk us through the specific weak perspective effect you want to achieve in your game? From my reading on weak perspective, it sounds like you could implement it as a regular orthographic camera, with scaling factors applied to each mesh instance (or in your vertex shader), but the details could vary depending on the particular look you want.

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you referring too? I guess something lower than 3.3 since I don't think it is much of a problem figuring it out if you are using shaders where you need to upload all your matrices manually.

Comment: @DMGregory Hi, there are two factors: [S,T], S is scale, T is transition

Comment: That's not a walkthrough of your intended effect. ;) Remember, we don't charge you by the letter here. There's nothing to be gained by sharing only minimal information. The more detail you can provide us, the better we can refine our answers to make sure they're great solutions for your specific needs. Please consider editing your question to include mock screenshots or diagrams of your intended look - these are often a big help for spatial/graphical questions - and samples of how your OpenGL code looks now. These details will help you get high-quality, actionable answers.